# disable forms authentication using Microsoft.Web.Administration

Tags: iis, forms, authentication, iis-7, administration

Anyone has a clue how to turn off forms authentication using Microsoft.Web.Administration and C#?

Comment: Not sure with Microsoft.Web.Administration but you can do it command line and run it with Process.Start:
appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:system.web/authentication /mode:Windows

Comment: I don't need to turn on windows auth, I need to turn off forms auth.

Comment: true, but it has the same side effect :) I hope someone can give you a proper answer.

Comment: @PCurd, when I turn on windows auth, then the forms auth still stays turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to change the web.config of the web site and set

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
```

to

```
 <authentication mode="Windows">
```